# htmlspecialcharacters_decode / html_entities_decode - result not being interpretted as HTML

Tags: php, php-5.3

As the title suggests - I have a situation where I am iterating over a series of decoded html (attempted with both htmlspecialcharacters_decode() and html_entities_decode). However the decoded string is treated as a textNode by the DOM. php 5.3.28

sample :

```
    <div>
      <h1>This is in the middle of a template file</h1>
        <?php
            foreach ($assocArrayObjEle as $obyKey => $obyMeat) {
                 if (!is_null($obyMeat->description) &&  strlen($obyMeat->description)> 0)
                 {
                 print html_entity_decode($obyMeat->description);
                 }  
                }
        ?>
    </div>
```

the result comes back as such :

## This is in the middle of a template file

<p>this is html, the brackets are not escaped as entity sequences - but this body of text is treated as an HTML text node. This doesn't seem to be the expected result per the manual entries and what reading on the topic I have found. All entities are properly handled, but the result is simply retreated as the textNode in the DOM, not a DOM element. Thanks in Advance</p>

as the sample output states - the entities are indeed re-factored into valid markup but they are appended to the DOM (or rather the DOM decides this?) that this is the value of the containing element's textNode - rather than a DOMElement set. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for whatever reason, a single pass of htmlspecialchars_decode() was not complete. This is extremely odd, because `&lt;` would otherwise need to appear as  `&amp;lt;` to necessitate this - whatever, going to leave this here if anyone else needs it. solution looks like :

```
<div>
      <h1>This is in the middle of a template file</h1>
        <?php
            foreach ($assocArrayObjEle as $obyKey => $obyMeat) {
                 if (!is_null($obyMeat->description) &&  strlen($obyMeat->description)> 0)
                 {
                     echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($obyMeat->description,  ENT_QUOTES), ENT_NOQUOTES); //2nd pass was necessary even tho there were no double escaped entites (amperstands not being double escaped).
                 }  
                }
        ?>
    </div>
```